# IOS :- Inapp purchase without application login & restoreCompletedTransactions

Tags: ios, swift

I have implemented inapp purchase in my application. but i have problem i don't have any login part in my application. and i want to store transaction history for particular user on my server. but how would i get apple id for my sucessful transaction. i need any unique id for particular user. who do inapp purcahse.

and another  question is that i have  non consumable in app purcahse for that we need to do  SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions().  there is no any restore button in my application so where should i do restore functionality.

Comment: You cannot obtain the purchaser's Apple ID.  To restore purchases you can either check the application receipt or adda restore purchase button (I recommend the latter)

Comment: I could not fount receipt in ios 10 inapppurchase code. and can you tell me please then how would i recognize particular user for transaction ?

Comment: The receipt is obtained in iOS 10 exactly as it was in prior versions.  This is discussed in the In-App Purchase Programming guide.  You can't get a user for a transaction; you can only get the transaction identifier from the receipt.

Comment: can you please give me the example file